# join in mysql between two table with on to many relation

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

i have two table like this:

phones

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a20 | 100 |
| 2 | a30 | 200 |

models:

| id | phone_id | model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a20-128GB |
| 2 | 1 | a20-256GB |
| 3 | 2 | a30-128GB |
| 4 | 2 | a30-256GB |
| 5 | 2 | a30-512GB |

i want to write SQL to give result like this:

| id | name | price | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a20 | 100 | a20-128GB |
| 2 | a20 | 100 | 200-256GB |
| 3 | a30 | 200 | 100-128GB |
| 4 | a30 | 200 | 200-256GB |
| 5 | a30 | 200 | 200-512GB |

i try left join but cant success
i try somthing like this:

```
SELECT `phones`.* , `models`.`phone_id` , `models`.`model` 
FROM `phones` 
LEFT JOIN `models` 
ON `phones`.id = `models`.`phone_id`
```

but model column retunr null

Comment: Also show us your join attempt.

Comment: The result's model column values look a bit a strange. As intended?

Comment: Typo -  `models`,`model`  SHOULD BE `models` dot `model`

Comment: I recommend to DO NOT use * within your query, but TO DO use table alias. Likely you're after this query: SELECT 
  m.id, p.name, p.price, m.model
FROM phones p 
LEFT JOIN models m
  ON p.id = m.phone_id. The last column of your result table looks strange, I guess this is some copy-paste issue. Otherwise you need to explain  the logic how to build the values of this column. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0567f6/2

Comment: 'but model column retunr null'-actual error returned by original code posting is Unknown column 'models' in 'field list' , running the (inadvertently?) corrected code works as expected see https://dbfiddle.uk/L5HUn9RI . so how did you see null I wonder.

Comment: @P.Salmon The query in your fiddle does not produce the same result as shown in the question. In your fiddle, the first column will be filled with phones.id. In the result shown above, it will be filled with models.id. Of course, we don't know what is intended ;)

Comment: @Jonas Metzler  'corrected code works as expected ' - I didn't mean to infer it produces OP's desired outcome...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This query should work for you:

```sql
SELECT m.id, p.name, p.price, m.model
FROM phones p
INNER JOIN models m ON p.id = m.phone_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, m.model
FROM phones p
CROSS JOIN models m
WHERE m.phone_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id, m.id;
```

Comment: CROSS JOIN with join condition in the WHERE clause - very odd choice. I'd recommend the regular JOIN ON syntax instead. (I.e. `FROM phones p JOIN models m ON m.phone_id = p.id`.)